# Can't validate form CakePHP 3

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp

I'm new on CakePHP and I can't validate a login form. I'm getting the following error: Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template\Users\login.ctp, line 5]

I already tried to use this code: `<?= $this->Form->create('User'); ?>` The error is removed but the validation doesn't works.

Can someone help me?

**login.ctp**:

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-5  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create($user); ?>

             <?php

            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
                ?>

            <?= $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**login function - UsersController.php**:

```
 // Login

    public function login()
    {      

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();

            if($user)
            {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comentario']);
            }

            // Erro no Login

            $this->Flash->error('Erro de autenticação');
        }


    }
```

Comment: First you need to read it first . this will clear you what you want  :http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

Comment: my register.ctp has working validation. I just want to know why I can't validate login.ctp. And I already read these tutorials, thanks for answer.

Comment: validate user or validate form field

Comment: I need to validate form, verify for empty fields etc.. I can't do this on login.ctp, but in register.ctp I can do normally. I copied the register.ctp code to login.ctp and nothing.

Comment: first you have to create model and entity for you table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change this line

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user); ?>
```

to this

```
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
```

Then, you can simplify your submit like this

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
```

Make sure you create UsersTable.php in you src/Model/Table and put this code

```
// src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator
            ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required')
    }

}
```

It's not good using redirect the specific controller inside login method. Change it:

```
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
```

Then tell your Auth Component where user should be redirect after login

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Articles',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
```

And the most important. Read [Authentication and Authorization Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)